# Are all computable functions fixed-point computable?

Tags: real-analysis, machine-learning, computability

A while ago I read the machine learning paper [Deep Equilibrium Models](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2019/hash/01386bd6d8e091c2ab4c7c7de644d37b-Abstract.html), which proposes to use a neural network model as follows: (1) during the forward pass, run a fixed point iteration $z_{n+1} = f(z_n, x)$ until convergence. To update the model via gradient descent, one can use the implicit function theorem.

This got me thinking: What kind of functions can be computed in this way? I suspect that similar to RNNs, one could maybe show Turing completeness ([Siegelmann & Sontag 1992](http://binds.cs.umass.edu/papers/1992_Siegelmann_COLT.pdf)). First we need a formalization of what we mean with "fixed-point computability". Towards this end, I came up with the following definition:

> We say a computable function $f\colon X\to Y$ is **fixed-point computable** if and only if there exists a finite dimensional space $Z$, an **elementary computable function** $g$ and constants $c_1$, $c_2$ such that the following diagram commutes: [image]

- $X, Y,Z$ are assumed to be finite dimensional real vector spaces (or appropriate subsets thereof).
- Regarding **elementary computability**, a couple of different definitions seem possible:

  1. **[Polynomial functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial#Polynomial_functions)**, i.e. everything that can be done with a finite number of additions and products
  2. **[Rational functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function)**, i.e. everything that can be done with a finite number of additions, multiplications, or divisions.
  3. **[Piece-wise Polynomial/Rational Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise)**, i.e. everything that can be done with a finite number of additions, multiplications/divisions or [Iverson Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) / if-else clauses based on the elementary field relations $(<, ≤, =, ≥, >)$, so in particular including functions like $\operatorname{sign}(x)=[x≥ 0]-[x≤ 0]$ or $\max(x, y)= x⋅[x ≥ y] + y⋅[y> x]$
- Note that all of the above function classes have the property that they map rational numbers to rational numbers (given that the coefficients are rational as well)
- Assung convergence, $g^\infty$ denotes the function $g^∞(ξ)=\lim\limits_{n→∞} \underbrace{(g∘g∘…∘ g)}_{n\;\text{times}}(ξ)$
- Note that $g^∞$ does not necessarily map rationals to rationals, even if $g$ does.
- The dimensionality of $Z$ can be interpreted as the "buffer memory" required to carry out the computation

It seems that already with this first draft of a definition, we can show many computable functions are in fact fixed point computable, by bringing them into the required form.

#### Example

If a function can be represented by a Taylor Series whose coefficients can be computed iteratively by elementary functions, we can bring it into "fixed-point form". Consider for instance

$$  g(x, y, k) = \begin{pmatrix}x, & y+\frac{x^{1/k}}{(1/k)!}, & \frac{1}{\frac{1}{k}+1}\end{pmatrix}$$

Which, when initialized with $y=1$, $k=1$ reproduced the series:

$$
g^{(n)}(x, 1, 1) 
= \Big(x, ∑_{k=0}^n \frac{x^n}{n!}, \frac{1}{n}\Big)
⟶(x, e^x, 0)
$$

Thus, we have proven that the exponential function is (rational) fixed-point computable.

#### Questions

1. Is this a useful definition? How could it be improved? Does there already exist the concept of fixed-point computablity somewhere in the literature?
2. Are all computable functions fixed-point computable?

Comment: Your proposal assumes some basic notion of computation with real numbers. There are good notions of [computable reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number), but they don't support what you are trying to do. Equality between computable reals is not computable. So detecting when a computable sequence of computable reals converges is not computable (even if you know that the sequence is eventually constant). Exact computation with [algebraic reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number) is possible, so they may be of interest.

Comment: @RobArthan Thanks for your comment. First of, for the purpose of this question it is irrelevant whether we can detect that the sequence is converging or not, we only care about existence here.

Secondly, you are right, if we restrict the piece-wise rational function-class to computable numbers it doesn't quite work out. But I believe that could be fixed one way or the other by either weakening the notion of equality to approximate equality, or by strengthening the model of computation. I am no expert in computability and any suggestions to fix up the definitions are very welcome!

Comment: @RobArthan Do you think we might possibly get away with restricting $g$ to rational numbers? Of course, $g^\infty$ then still would map to real numbers, in general.